# Selecting the right else statement depending on user input

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I'm working on a little program where the user inputs a price and then the program would output the shipping cost based on the input.

```
#Initilaize variables

lowUS = 6.00;
medUS = 9.00;
highUS = 12.00;
lowCan = 8.00;
medCan = 12.00;
highCan = 15.00;

#Greet user and ask for input
print("Welcome to Ben's shipping calculator!");
print("We will calculate your shipping cost for you!");


orderTotal = float(input("Please input your total amount."));
country = input("In which country do you reside? Please type C for Canada or U or USA. ");

#Validate input
while country not in {'u', 'c', 'C', 'U'}:
    print ("Invalid input. Please try again. ")
    country = input("In which country do you reside? Please type C for Canada or U or USA. ");

#Determine how much the shipping fee is
if country == 'U' or country == 'u':
    if orderTotal <= 50.00:
        if orderTotal > 50.00 and orderTotal <= 100.00:
            if orderTotal > 100.00 and orderTotal <= 150.00:
                if orderTotal > 150.00:
                    print("Your shipping is free and your grand total is", orderTotal)
                else:
                    print("Your shipping fee is: ", highUS);
                    orderTotal = (orderTotal + highUS); 
            else:
                print("Your shipping fee is: ", medUS);
                orderTotal = (orderTotal + medUS);
        else:
            print("Your shipping fee is: ", lowUS);
            orderTotal = (orderTotal + lowUS);

elif country == 'c' or country == 'C':
    if orderTotal <= 50.00:
        if orderTotal > 50.00 and orderTotal <= 100.00:
            if orderTotal > 100.00 and orderTotal <= 150.00:
                if orderTotal > 150.00:
                    print("Your shipping is free and your grand total is", orderTotal)
                else:
                    print("Your shipping fee is: ", highCan);
                    orderTotal = (orderTotal + highCan); 
            else:
                print("Your shipping fee is: ", medCan);
                orderTotal = (orderTotal + medCan);
        else:
            print("Your shipping fee is: ", lowCan);
            orderTotal = (orderTotal + lowCan);

print("Your grand total is: $", orderTotal);
```

I am very new to python and programming and I'm not sure if this is a good way to go at it, but I'm learning if-else statements so I thought I would give it a try. So far it only works if you input "50" for the amount. It will calculate based off of the country only for "50". I'm not sure where I went wrong, if someone could help and explain, that would be great.

Comment: Your first `if` only enters if it's less than or equal to 50... the next check you make is if it's greater than 50 which it can't be - so that block will never execute... So your `else` clause is the only one that can execute...

Comment: Python has no line terminator besides a newline - those semicolons are completely unnecessary. This isn't C! (or Java, or JavaScript, or anything else)

Answer (score 1):

Your first `if` only enters if it's less than or equal to 50... the next check you make is if it's greater than 50 which it can't be - so that block will never execute... So your `else` clause is the only one that can execute... Basically, your nested `if` statements won't execute because the criteria for doing so is already excluded from the enclosing `if`.

You're best off restructuring your logic as:

```
if orderTotal > 150:
    # do something
elif orderTotal > 100:
    # do something
elif orderTotal > 50:
    # do something
else: # 50 or under...
    # do something else
```

Comment: Okay I see the mistake now, i was actually thinking about doing it this way, but was not 100% sure if it would have been correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a bit screwy. If the amount is <= $50, then it is not > $50 or <= $100, so anything following that nested "if" will never execute:

```
if orderTotal <= 50.00:
    if orderTotal > 50.00 and orderTotal <= 100.00:
        # ** this will never run **
    else:
        # This will run, if orderTotal <= 50.00
```

Nothing will happen if `orderTotal > 50.00`, because there's no `else` for the `if orderTotal <= 50.00` test. @Jon Clements' answer shows the correct way to structure your code.